# Change Avatar Hands Material In Oculus Quest

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

what is the procedure of changing the avatar's hands material in Oculus Quest?
Atm, it appears white and to me, it looks like someone forgot to place material.

I tried to change the prefabs colors but it didn't work as it seems like everything is assigned on runtime.

in the avatar hands material manager, there is a whole palate of skin colors but the color of the appearing hands are still white.

If anyone can direct me:

1. whats the correct prefab (i played around with any "hand" prefab I could find.
2. how can I take advantage of the DefaultHandMaterialManager